# create trigger merges firstname and lastname fields into one on field update or insert

Tags: mysql

I am trying to learn more about MySQL triggers

I need a trigger that merges firstname and lastname columns into one fullname column when that firstname or lastname field is updated or a new row is created/inserted

Something like?

```
CREATE TRIGGER `fullname` BEFORE INSERT ON users 
FOR EACH ROW Set users.fullname = CONCAT(users.firstname, ' ', users.lastname);
```

Comment: A [generated column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) might be a smarter solution ?

Comment: @Luuk My purpose is to create a full-text index on that fullname field

Comment: @Luuk also it seems like generated column cannot be updated

Comment: But when you define a trigger, an update on `fullname` will also not have much effect...

Comment: @Luuk why is that? can I change a column to generated column?

Comment: [ALTER TABLE and Generated Columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table-generated-columns.html)  (TL;DR that one )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Within the trigger body, the OLD and NEW keywords enable you to access columns in the rows affected by a trigger' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

in other words

```
CREATE TRIGGER `fullname` BEFORE INSERT ON users 
FOR EACH ROW Set NEW.fullname = CONCAT(NEW.firstname, ' ', NEW.lastname);
```

and in an update trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER `fullname` BEFORE update ON users 
    FOR EACH ROW Set NEW.fullname = CONCAT(NEW.firstname, ' ', NEW.lastname);
```

NB mysql does not have an insert and update trigger you need one of each

Comment: Thank you. Does that update trigger works when any field is updated? If yes, can I limit it to work only when firstname or lastname field is updated?

Comment: mysql triggers fire on any update (even if nothing is updated) you can decide what should happen using IF..then...END IF see manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/if.html